# WPF remove/close/dispose CustomControl from the CustomControl

Tags: wpf, custom-controls, visualtreehelper

I have a `CustomControl` with some elements and a `Button`.
I want to remove/close/dispose the `CustomControl` when the `Button` clicked.
I tried to get the parent of the element when the `Button` is clicked but all I get is crush.

My `CustomControl` is `TabItem` and I want to remove it from the `TabControl` , so to get the `TabControl` I use the following code (and it crushes):

`TabControl parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(this) as TabControl;`

What am I doing wrong? Maybe my approach is wrong? If so, how can I remove/close/dispose the `TabItem` when the `Button` is clicked?

Thanks

Comment: you custom control is deriving TabItem or is a usercontrol placed inside TabItem of TabControl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent of your CustomControl will still be TabItem. Try below code:

Clears the content of TabItem:

```
        TabItem tabItem = this.Parent as TabItem;
        tabItem.Content = null;
```

If you want to remove the TabItem from TabControl then:

```
        ((TabControl)tabItem.Parent).Items.Remove(tabItem);
```